# Spherical wave as sum of plane waves

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, mathematics

How can we do this computation?

$$\iiint_{R^3} \frac{e^{ik'r}}{r} e^{ik_1x+k_2y+k_3z}dx dy dz$$
where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$? I think we must use distributions.

Physically, it's equivalent to find wave vectors $k$ distribution and to write a spherical wave as sum of plane waves.
I know the formula for the inverse problem: write a plane wave as sum of spherical waves. The solution in this case is a serie of spherical harmonics and spherical bessel functions.

Comment: This is the 3D Fourier transform of $\frac{e^{ik'r}}r$? If so, the formula should be $\iiint_V \frac{e^{ik'r}}r e^{{\color{red}-}i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r} d^3\mathbf r$

Comment: It's the same: like in 1D: you can define Fourier trasform as $\int f(x) e^{\pm ikx}dx$, and the inverse trasform is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\widetilde f(k) e^{\mp ikx}dk$ ;-)

Comment: Yeah of course, but the definition of the wave vector will be in the opposite direction.

Comment: This question might have a physical motivation but I think it is purely mathematical in nature. You should probably ask for the answer at math.SE.

Comment: @Marek: I think I agree... I mean, the title suggests a physics question, but in essence it is just about how to do an integral. I'm voting to close it (but only because it requires four other people to agree before the question actually gets closed - I wouldn't be comfortable unilaterally closing this if I had the power to do so).

Comment: @David: I'm sorry but I didn't know if the question was resolvable with "rigorous method", or this could be very complicated, so I asked here because I thought that some physicist knowed this simple problem was more probable, even if the solution wasn't "rigorous"...I have already posted questions like this...I'm sorry, if you want I delete this question...

Comment: @David: right, I also wouldn't be comfortable to just close it on my own. @Boy: no need to be sorry, closing a question is no big deal. It's really more about setting boundaries of what should and shouldn't be asked on this site so that people know in the future.

Comment: I know I'm in the minority, but I like seeing these "mathematical" questions here.  Physicists have a different culture of math than mathematicians, and are more likely to get a useful answer from other physicists.

Comment: @nibot: although I disagree (for now), that is an excellent point. And @Boy Simone: I completely agree with Marek's last comment, there's no need to be sorry. You haven't done anything wrong by asking this question (and in fact you're helping us define the scope of this site).

Comment: @David, @Marek, I agree with @nibot. We have a tag in this site called Mathematical Physics and I think this type of question merits that tag and thus belongs to this site. Sometimes we don't need an all too rigorous or involved mathematical answer to a mathematical question and that's when a physicist's view may be helpful. So I hope this type of question doesn't get closed in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [answer by kennytm](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/1526/21441) is only partially correct. It finds all the values of the Fourier image—where they exist. But the complete Fourier image of a spherical wave is not a function: it's a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).

Let's consider a standing wave described in terms of the $0$th order spherical Bessel function (the imaginary part of the OP's function):

$$g(\mathbf r)=k'j_0(k'r)=\frac{\sin(k'r)}r.$$

We can find its Fourier transform similarly to the approach in the **kennytm**'s answer, but with a special treatment of the final integral:

$$I=\int_0^\infty \sin(k'r)\sin kr dr.$$

This integral (up to multiplicative constant) is the [sine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_sine_transform) of $\sin(k'r)$, which is equal to

$$I=\delta(k-k')-\delta(k+k'),$$

where $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta).

Similarly we can find that the Fourier transform of the second spherical wave—the one with $0$th order spherical Neumann function (the real part of the OP's function):

$$h(\mathbf r)=k'y_0(k'r)=\frac{\cos(k'r)}r.$$

Fourier transforming of this one would reduce (up to constant multiplier) to taking the sine transform of the $\cos(k'r)$, and we'll finally get the same Fourier transform as in **kennytm**'s answer:

$$\mathcal F[h](k\hat{\mathbf z})=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\frac1{k^2 - k'^2}.$$

Now we can compile the complete Fourier transform of the running wave given in the OP:

$$f(\mathbf r)=\frac{e^{ik'r}}r.$$

It's the combination of the two results found above:

$$\boxed{\mathcal{F}[f](k\hat{\mathbf z})=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\frac1{k^2 - k'^2}+\frac i k\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\big(\delta(k-k')-\delta(k+k')\big).}$$

Comment: I think that the answer is:

$$
\mathcal F[f](k\hat{\mathbf z})=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{k^2-k'^2}+\frac{i}{k}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\delta(k-k')-\delta(k+k')\right).
$$

I have added the comments with calculations to kennytm's answer.

Comment: @rtmd you're right, I've now fixed the answer.

Comment: It's quite odd that the sin spherical wave is monochromatic ($|k'| = |k|$), whereas the cos spherical wave is not. The difference between the two appears to just be a phase shift in real space ... I'm surprised that that results in the production of new more k values. Any intuition on that?

Comment: @ionsme note that spherical sin is finite at the origin (the so called first remarkable limit), while spherical cos is singular.

Answer (score 14):

From your description, I believe you want to find the Fourier transform of 
$$ f(\mathbf r) = \frac{e^{ik'r}}r, $$
and the wave can be recovered from the linear superposition of plane waves identified by **k**
$$ f(\mathbf r) = \frac1{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\iiint \mathcal F[f](\mathbf k)e^{i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r} d^3 \mathbf k. $$

The spherical wave have spherical symmetry, so what you should do is to perform the integration in spherical coordinates instead of Cartesian. WLOG, assume **k** is along the *z* axis, thus
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal F[f](k\hat{\mathbf z}) &= \frac1{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \iiint \frac{e^{ik'r}}r e^{-i\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf r} d^3\mathbf r \\
&= \frac1{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \iiint \frac{e^{ik'r}}r e^{-ikr\cos\theta} r^2 \sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi \\
&= \frac1{(2\pi)^{1/2}} \int_0^\infty \left(re^{ik'r} \int_0^{\pi} e^{-ikr\cos\theta} \sin\theta d\theta\right) dr \\
&= \frac1{(2\pi)^{1/2}}  \int_0^\infty r e^{ik'r} \frac{2 \sin kr}{kr} dr \\
&= \frac1k\sqrt{\frac2\pi}  \int_0^\infty e^{ik'r} \sin kr dr \\
&= \sqrt{\frac2\pi}\frac1{k^2 - k'^2}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: thank you! And how have you do the last passage? $1/k \int_0^{+infty} e^{ik'r}sinkrdr= \frac{1}{k^2+k'^2}$

Comment: @Boy: What do you mean?

Comment: I think he wants to know how your last step of the calculation is done, i.e. the integral over $e^{ik' r}\sin kr$.

Comment: @Boy: Change $\sin kr$ to $(e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr})/2i$. Then notice that $\int_0^\infty e^{iKr} dr = i/K$ (if we ignore convergence stuff. Actually the answer isn't right when $k'$ doesn't have a positive imaginary part since the integral diverges.)

Comment: Yes, then I arrived at that consideration too. My doubt is just it, a k' purely real means no absorption, but I think that you can't explain a purely spherical wave with plane waves is very strange, because the inverse is possible...Maybe there's the way to do convergence of that integral in distrubution sense...like $\int e^{ikx}=2\pi \delta(k)$...I post the question on the mathematical section too, because that's really purely mathematical...Thank you :-)

Comment: PS, Yeha, I think that it's the same: it's similar to the antitrasform in the solution of the Poisson Equation, when you find the Green Function...! :-)

Comment: When doing the last integral one has to ensure the convergence of the integral by shifting $k'$ slightly in to the complex: $(k'+i\epsilon), \epsilon > 0$.
For an incoming wave $e^{-ik'r}/r$ one has to choose $(k'-i\epsilon), \epsilon > 0$.
Otherwise incoming and outgoing spherical waves would have the same Fourier transform.

Comment: This answer misses the imaginary part. See [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/664166/21441) for the fix.

Comment: $\int_0^{+\infty} e^{ik'r}\sin{kr} dr=\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{i(k'+k)r}dr-\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{i(k'-k)r}dr$.

$\int_0^{+\infty}e^{i\omega t}dt=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\theta(t)e^{i\omega t}dt=\frac{1}{-i\omega}+\pi\delta(\omega)$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions,_one-dimensional (item 313, third version of the Fourier transform), here $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside function.

$\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{i(k'+k)r}dr=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{-i(k'+k)}+\pi\delta(k'+k)\right)=\frac{1}{2(k'+k)}-i\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(k'+k)$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{i(k'-k)r}dr=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{-i(k'-k)}+\pi\delta(k'-k)\right)=\frac{1}{2(k'-k)}-i\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(k'-k)$.

$$
\int_0^{+\infty} e^{ik'r}\sin{kr} dr=\frac{1}{2(k'+k)}-\frac{1}{2(k'-k)}-i\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(k'+k)+i\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(k'-k)=\\
=\frac{k}{k^2-k'^2}+i\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\delta(k-k')-\delta(k+k')\right)
$$

Comment: The final answer is: $\mathcal F[f](k\hat{\mathbf z})=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{k^2-k'^2}+\frac{i}{k}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\delta(k-k')-\delta(k+k')\right)$.